# Crash on ActivityThread.handleBindApplication when updating AndroidManifest.xml, rollback still crash

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

I had a warning *Exported receiver does not require permission* in my AndroidManifest.xml about this receiver :

```
<receiver android:name="org.thieftracker.SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />               
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>                  
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I understand the problem, I fix it by changing first line with :

```
<receiver android:name="org.thieftracker.SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
```

But it crashes on debug launch.
I roll back by removing the `android:exported="false"`
but it still crashes on :  `ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread$AppBindData) line: 4070`

I tried to clean the project, it still crashes. 
My only solution it to delete my whole workspace and copy back a backup !
I guess it comes from the Eclipse IDE.
Any idea ?

**UPDATE :**
Found it !
I forgot to put a permission in my AndroidManifest (WAKE_LOCK).
I still don't understand why it used to work when the permission was missing. I guess it comes from some cache/update stuff over AndroidManifest.xml
I also lost a lot of time because I did not know how to use LogCat and DDMS view. About that, I still don't know where to find the stack trace !
I put back the bug, and I am still fighting with IDE to find again the stack trace with the magic

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application org.thieftracker.ThiefTracker: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10029 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

Where the hell did I get it ?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure try this:`<receiver android:name="org.thieftracker.SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">`

Comment: That's what I did (see my original post)

Comment: I think there might be some else which create problem. Will please post your logcat here